# Using PowerShell to list domains of a Primary Zone and create cnames?

Tags: powershell, dns

As a service to my companies DNS admin I want to create a PowerShell script that adds a whole lot of DNS Cnames. That is fine as long as I create my domains all as primary domains. But, now I just realized that this it not the setup on our production server. There they have created a forward lookup zone and then added domains underneath it to get

- yourdomain.com
- test.yourdomain.com
- qa.yourdomain.com

[image: DNS Manager]

My issues now is that I do not know either how to list those subdomains using PowerShell, nor create cnames within them. The below code is working as long as test.yourdomain.com is a primary zone, but how can I add it to the test "sub-domain". And which cmdlet to list the content of the test.yourdomain.com?

```
Add-DnsServerResourceRecordCName -Name myappdnsalias -HostNameAlias proxyserver.yourdomain.com -ZoneName test.yourdomain.com -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -verbose
```

Using Windows 2016/2019

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating was solved by simply adding the name of the domain folder to the name of the alias

```
Add-DnsServerResourceRecordCName -Name myapp.test -HostNameAlias proxyserver.yourdomain.com -ZoneName yourdomain.com -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -verbose
```

And then when issuing

```
Get-DnsServerResourceRecord -ComputerName mydnsserver -ZoneName yourdomain.com
```

it will list domains like

```
HostName    RecordType Type Timestamp TimeToLive      RecordData
--------    ---------- ---- --------- ----------      ----------
myapp.test  CNAME      5    0         01:00:00        proxyserver.yourdomain.com
```